# Get a single record from a record set

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Simple request:

```
    a1 = where(MyModel, [x], is_nil(x.some_foreign_id)) |> Repo.one()
```

Exception:

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:                                
    ** (Ecto.MultipleResultsError) expected at most one result but got 6 in query:
```

Yes, there're a few records and that's ok, but my intention is to take the 1st one. Why exception and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why the exception

`Repo.one` always returns nil or one record, and it would be better if the programmer adds the `limit` to the query themselves rather than fetching more records from the database and then throwing all but one.

> how to fix it?

You can use `limit(1)`:

```
a1 = where(MyModel, [x], is_nil(x.some_foreign_id)) |> limit(1) |> Repo.one()
```

Note that without an `order`, which record is returned is usually undefined in most databases. You can order by `id` to get the record with the lowest `id`:

```
a1 = where(MyModel, [x], is_nil(x.some_foreign_id)) |> order_by(:id) |> limit(1) |> Repo.one()
```